# Is it safe to do light Plyometrics even though lower calves are sore

Tags: plyometrics

Here's my routine

Plyometrics
20 jumping jacks
40 ghost jump ropes (I don't use real rope)
60 jogging steps

I interleave 4 sets of Plyometrics between three sets of weight-training.

Lower calves are still slightly sore after two days (even when I walk I can feel the soreness), but I really want to get up and work out!!!!!!!!

Is it safe for beginner to do so after lot of stretching, or is it better to wait another day?

Comment: Regarding stretching prior to working out [here is some pertinent info](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12813/pre-workout-static-vs-dynamic-stretches).

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy Thank God, because I find stretching to be a nuisance, especially when you are amped and ready to go go go!!!!!

Comment: Do also read the links in the comments regarding "dynamic stretching" or warm ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it safe to do light Plyometrics even though lower calves are sore?**

**Yes**. Since you are having a slight soreness, it is still alright to do plyometrics so long you **do not do any sort of heavy calf raises**.

Comment: Nothing heavy of the sort.