# warming up to increase splits

Tags: flexibility, splits

I'm working currently on increasing flexibility in my adductors (specifically the left leg, since it is stiffer than my right), and eventually would like to be able to do a full side split. Should I be warmed up to do my split stretches, or would I be fine simply doing the stretches standalone, without a warmup?

If I do need to warm up to effectively increase flexibility, what sort of warm up would suffice?

Comment: Here is a good place to start your research https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12813/pre-workout-static-vs-dynamic-stretches