# What are some stretching exercises for golf?

Tags: stretching

I have heard of stretching your hip flexors and shoulders. Simply googling is leaving me with a bad taste on explanation on which stretching exercises to do, and especially on detail information on how to do them.

Does anyone have a good source for such information? I am as young as I would like to be, hence me needing more stretching prior to practicing my bad swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good write up on stretching in general

[Should I stretch after exercise?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/455/should-i-stretch-after-exercise)

Rather than stretching prior to playing, you would probably be better off with a warm up. You could base a warm up around swing a club, twists and bends for five or ten minutes until you feel your body has wormed / loosend up. You can stretch after playing

A source of stretching exercises:
http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/rehabilitation-exercises/stretching-exercises

A good stretch lasts ten to twenty seconds and shouldn't be painful.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Stretching is something that I had always been told to do prior, which makes me wonder if it is simply an old mentality on the way things should go. I will definitely try stretching after as you mentioned. Hopefully that way my muscles might feel a bit lose afterwards.

Comment: @ASalcedo - Stretching beforehand is absolutely indicated. The swinging of a club, twists, bends, etc. are a type of stretching called dynamic stretching, and that is recommended before activity. It is the typical reach and hold type (called static stretching) that is not recommended for before activity.

Comment: @ JohnP You are correct. I should have been more specific, regarding static stretching.