# Work around ligament light pain

Tags: weightlifting, injury, pain

Related to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/how-do-i-promote-connective-tissue-health-strength), but not the same.

Case:

You have a light ligament pain and you strength train.

A medical professional has cleared you out for exercising.

What's the path that minimizes the loss of strength and progress while maximizing the chances of a good recovery?

- Skip all sessions involving that ligament until there is no pain at all
- Change the movement so there is less or ideally no pain (for example Zotmann curls, to Hammer curls if you have elbow pain)
- Reduce the intensity and do more reps so the strain on the ligament is less
- Both changing the movement and reducing intensity

Any of the above or some other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend trying out what works best for you and your body.

If you have pain *while you lift*, stop the lift and try another one that hits the same muscle groups that has less pressure on that ligament.  If you cannot find another lift, stop altogether for a period of time or try lighter weight.

If you have pain *without lifting*, try lighter weight and low reps, and focus on strengthening the muscles around the ligament. Only increase reps and weight when you are no longer in pain.

A great way to get back into working out after being hurt or having pain is physical therapy or at the very least doing physical therapy exercises.  There are usually a ton of sites, videos, and guides to exercises and stretches that will be light on pain and strengthen the areas that are needed. [SportyDoctor](https://sportydoctor.com/) seems to have some really detailed exercises, great diagrams, and even goes into detail about the muscles themselves.