# Stretching during exercises?

Tags: muscle, stretching

Is it correct to make a brief stretching session even during physical activity, and not just at the end?

Comment: This is something that varies from person to person, so you're just gonna have to try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: Im on mobile so will answer more later but there are studies that show static stretching just before has a negative impact on power output.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is person-to-person at all.

Comment: just to add as a reference http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/455/should-i-stretch-after-exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there's no credible studies that show static stretching during exercise is helpful.  In fact, as a result of some recent studies, the opposite seems to be true.  That is, static stretching before and **during** a training session can have a negative effect.  A study by the Journal of Strength and Conditioning, [Chronic Effect of Static Stretching on Strength Performance and Basal Serum IGF-1 Levels](http://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Abstract/2013/09000/Chronic_Effect_of_Static_Stretching_on_Strength.14.aspx)
 found that strength training, performed without any form of stretching before or during, can more effectively increase muscle and basal serum IGF-1 levels (a muscle building hormone).

> In the new study, the participants either performed strength
>   training with stretching done before hand, strength training with
>   stretching done during sets (the sort of thing you see all the time in
>   the gym), and strength training alone. They compared the strength
>   results and levels of IGF-1, a muscle building hormone, in each of the
>   three groups after 10 weeks of training.

(http://breakingmuscle.com/mobility-recovery/static-stretching-before-during-and-after-lifting).

These findings were supported by a second study that was published in [The Scandinavian Journal of Medicine and Science in Sports](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22316148), leading many to believe that

> “stretching before exercise is not only unnecessary, but it may
>   actually be counterproductive, as well.”

The Scandinavian study concluded that...

> “We conclude that the usage of SS as the sole activity during warm-up
>   routine should generally be avoided. “

Since these studies were relatively short with a small control group, more research is needed. But, the general consensus is that static stretching is best when performed at the **end** of your training session.

Comment: This is pretty much what I would have answered, with a couple of the same references. +1.